# SQL Developer - Exporting to loader format expands fields' sizes in control file to match the length of column names when less

Tags: sql, oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

P.S
I've already solved this outside of SQL Developer by generating my own Control Files through a script using our internal data dictionary - but I'm still interested in understanding why this happens and whether or not it's working as intended due to limitations or by design.

**Background:**

I am attempting to export data from a simple select query in Oracle SQL Developer (Originally *Version 18.4.0.376 Build 376.1900*, now updated to Version *21.4.3.063 Build 063.0100* with no difference) from an Oracle 19c database ("Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.10.0.0.0") to the loader format by using the export option from the right-click context menu on the query results, later to be inserted in another database using the SQL*Loader utility.
Here are the settings used:
[Export Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vizc.png)

Some columns have the NUMBER data type, and when exporting the data I noticed that they drop their data type in the control file as they're classified as a non-portable data type due to platform dependencies. This leads to the SQL*Loader utility defaulting to CHAR (255). While this doesn't cause an issue with the data as I'm only handling integers (allowing for implicit conversion) - it does affect the Bindsize/Readsize requirements (some fields increase in size by more than a factor of 40) and effectively limits the number of rows I can insert, thus slowing down the process.

I tried working around this issue by CAST:ing the fields to CHAR/VARCHAR2 with a desired size - this led me to discover that certain columns get a different length/size from their table definitions or what I specified in the CAST. If they're shorter/smaller than the column name, they get extended to match the length of the column name in the loader Control File.

I'm very puzzled as to why this is happening. The fields in the database don't have this limitation.

Here are some examples:
Attempting this for SHIPTOSEQNO in SHIPPING_TABLE which has data type NUMBER(6):

```
select cast(SHIPTOSEQNO as CHAR(6)) from SHIPPING_TABLE;
```

this results in the following value being exported to the control file:

```
"SHIPTOSEQNO" CHAR (11)) #11 being the length of the column name
```

This happens for every field, and I just don't understand why.
More examples:

```
describe SHIPPING_TABLE;
CARRIERNO VARCHAR2(6) --excerpt from output
```

"Normal" select, field size extends to column name length:

```
select CARRIERNO from SHIPPING_TABLE;
"CARRIERNO" CHAR (9)) #value in control file
```

Renaming the field during select, field gets correct size from database:

```
select CARRIERNO as four from SHIPPING_TABLE;
"FOUR" CHAR (6)) #value in control file
```

Renaming the field after CAST:ing to a smaller size, field gets assigned the specified size as it doesn't exceed column name length:

```
select cast(CARRIERNO as CHAR(4)) as four from SHIPPING_TABLE;
"FOUR" CHAR (4)) #value in control file
```

CAST:ing the field to much bigger field size - the field gets the specified size as it greatly exceeds the length of the column name:

```
select cast(carrierno as CHAR(50)) as CARRIERNO from SHIPPING_TABLE;
"CARRIERNO" CHAR (50)) #value in control file
```

Renaming the field after CAST:ing to a desired size, specified size is disregarded and instead extended to match column name:

```
select cast(CARRIERNO as CHAR(6)) as LONGER_NAME_FOR_CARRIERNO from SHIPPING_TABLE;
"LONGER_NAME_FOR_CARRIERNO" CHAR (25)) #value in control file
```

I've already solved this outside of SQL Developer by generating my own Control Files through a script using our internal data dictionary - but I'm still interested in understanding why this happens and whether or not it's working as intended due to limitations or by design.

Thanks.

Comment: Given that the current version of SQL Developer is 21.4.3, have you tried upgrading?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the old software version. I've been using the installation supplied by our software repository and relied on the "Check for Updates" feature - but it apparently stopped working at some point I didn't realize how out of date it had gotten.

I downloaded the latest version, but regrettably the issue persists.

Comment: In case it's relevant, the database version is:
"Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.10.0.0.0"